# Why is projectile trajectory formula from Wiki giving odd results?

Tags: c#

So I got an equation from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile) to find the distance a projectile can travel with different given variables, such as angle and velocity (height and gravity are optional, height will default to 0). This is what it looks like in code:

```
dist = ((velocity * velocity) / 9.807f) * (float)Math.Sin(angle * 2);
```

I've also tried this:

```
dist = ((velocity * velocity) * (float)Math.Sin(angle * 2)) / 9.807f;
```

Neither of which give promising results. The first one gives me something like 91.... while the other one gives me a negative.

Thank you.

Comment: Does `angle` contain the angle in degrees or radians? Math.Sin requires radians.

Comment: I'd guess your angle is invalid, probably you forgot to convert it deg<->rad. Also, even so, it is not possible that just moving `/9.807f` like that has suddenly introduced negatives. Either they were already present in the first case, or you must have errors elsewhere too. Hard to say without rest of the code.

Comment: Also, is velocity in meters/second?

Comment: What about the number 91... makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the problem. @Heinzi, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be equivalent (should give the same answers for any values of the variables), and should both have given you the right answer if you used the correct units. You need to convert the angle into degrees. As @theB pointed out, velocity should be in meters per second, and the distance output will be in meters.

The best thing to do is to take the simplest possible number, for example velocity = 1, g = 10, and angle 45 degrees (pi/4 radians). Check that you get the right answer. It should be so simple that you can work out the results yourself with a calculator. Get that right first. Then use other values for the inputs, changing one at a time.

As @PeterSchneider says in the comments, it can be very useful to check values for which we immediately know the answer, such as 90 degrees, and 0 degrees. These might seem like pointless examples which would never be needed in real life. However, they have the following advantages as test cases:

- It is very easy to specify what the behavior should be.
- By checking these cases you might find a bug which affects other values.
- Conversely, you might find a bug in how you handle edge cases, which you would not otherwise have found, such a divide by zero.

Some edge cases can be quite tricky. What if gravity is zero?

You should probably put your code inside a function, which takes `velocity`, `g` and `angle` as arguments and returns the distance. This will allow you to easily try multiple different inputs.

There is a formalization of this kind of procedure, called **unit testing**. You write small pieces of testing code, which check different cases, starting with the simplest possible. Each time you make a change, you re-run your tests to make sure that everything still works. If you're interested, you could look at a unit testing framework for C# called NUnit. It comes as an add-in for VS and is very straightforward to use.

Comment: Good advice. You pre-compute or look up the correct, expected  results for your test values by other means. For example, we logically know that both 90 degrees -- straight up -- and 0 degrees (straight forward, hits the ground right away) should yield 0. These expected results are hard-wired (or computed with a known, working library) into the test, and the results of your function are compared against it. Careful with float comparisons: They usually require comparing intervals due to the unavoidable rounding errors involved.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that it needed to be radians... Silly noob me. Again, thanks for the answers, and all the comments. They steered me to the right direction.